# vs code formats yaml file with extra spaces between brackets

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I use vscode as an editor and have several yaml files in the project where parameter replacement occurs. However, it re-formats only one file with extra spaces between brackets, a file named service.yaml used by helm in our ci/cd pipeline. See below for before and after. [image]

and after [image]

I was wondering if the name of the file has particular significance for vscode or any other extensions... Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uncheck `Bracket Spacing` in `Extensions/YAML`.

[image]

**Edit**: There is a caveat. This will format `{{ foo }}` or `{ { foo } }` to  `{{foo}}`, which is not necessarily syntactically correct in terms of Jinja templating.

Comment: Good shout on the caveat. There doesn't seem to be a setting to accomplish the {{ foo }} spacing inside the double brackets.

Comment: As of Oct 17 2023 I don't have this setting in VSCode. This solution should work though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76978088/13199842

Answer (score 3):

One of the way how to resolve this issue - wrap values into the quotes.

Like this:

```
app: "{{ .Values.name }}"
```

Probably not the best solution, but it works for me.

Comment: It doesn't work for integer values though, even if you do `"{{ .Values.port | int }}"`. I got along fine like that until I needed to plug in port values. I've spent the last hour looking for a solution and have yet to find one

Answer (score 0):

VSCode has a command to "Save without Formatting".

I noticed that my indentation changes were altered when I saved the YAML file. However, if I press cmd + shift + p in Mac, and type Save without formatting, and click that command to save, my indentations are preserved.

For Mac, the same command can also be executed with the keyboard shortcut cmd + K + S

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR** - Just add all of your helm .yaml files to .prettierignore since they contain go text templates and are not supposed to be valid YAML anyway.

### The Full Explanation

I was encountering the same issue with prettier and did some investigating.  The actual answer is that the helm-generated service.yaml file *looks* like actual YAML where everything enclosed in `{{...}}` is interpreted to be a value.  When prettier runs on service.yaml, it just formats the file contents according to the prettier settings with the prettier console displaying a successful prettier run:

```
["INFO" - 10:37:59 PM] Formatting completed in 20ms.
```

This leaves the file in a bad state since `{ { .Values.service.port } }` is **not** a valid go template and therefore cannot be rendered by helm.

However, all of the other helm-generated .yaml files have some go templates for text rendering in places that are not intended to be valid YAML syntax.  For example, my serviceaccount.yaml file starts with:

```
{{- if .Values.serviceAccount.create -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
...
```

Note that this is not valid YAML syntax, so prettier throws an error, outputing something like this in the prettier console:

```
["ERROR" - 10:21:24 PM] Error formatting document.
["ERROR" - 10:21:24 PM] Document contains trailing content not separated by a ... or --- line (2:1)
   1 | {{- if .Values.serviceAccount.create -}}
>  2 | apiVersion: v1
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>  3 | kind: ServiceAccount
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>  4 | metadata:
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...<a whole lot of other errors followed by a stack trace>
["INFO" - 10:21:24 PM] Formatting completed in 21ms.
```

(Okay, okay, technically the first line actually is valid YAML document but to follow with `apiVersion: v1` on the next line would require a new document delimiter in the stream using either `...` or `---` line between, which would break helm anyway)

Since prettier can't successfully format the file as YAML, it just leaves the file as-is.

As the helm templates are not intended to be pure YAML, the solution is most likely just to add all of those files to .prettierignore and move on with life.

Comment: I don't think its a great idea to turn of formatting, you may want do saving without formatting on vscode.